# MS Access Query to retrieve records with lasted date in orderdate column

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have table in Access Database with the following columns

```
ProductID|ProductName|StoreID|StoreName|AuditRating|AuditVisit|NextAuditDue
100100   |Calculator |SC12345|CrawlyRoad| B        |11/12/2013|21/02/2014
100100   |Calculator |SC12345|CrawlyRoad| A        |11/12/2014|30/04/2015
100100   |Calculator |SC12345|CrawlyRoad| C        |16/12/2015|24/01/2017
```

I need to make a query which will only give me the distinct record where the AuditVisit date is maximum like in this case I only want the third row

```
100100   |Calculator |SC12345|CrawlyRoad| C        |16/12/2015|24/01/2017
```

I have used `group by` but as I need to bring all the columns I am getting all the records as the AuditRating column is different in all three rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TOP 1:

```
Select Top 1 * From YourTable Order By AuditVisit Desc
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav your solution works I just need to check if it works on the entire table, will mark it as answer :)

Comment: brilliant it worked on the entire table thanks a lot for help, please rate the question too :)

Comment: sorry I have just found that this solution has changed all the date column values to the same maximum date which is incorrect.

Comment: It cannot "change" anything - it's a straight select query - so you are probably thinking of something else.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that it has picked the maximum dates for both the column and only picked the records where the dates matches the maximum dates value that is why all the records have same dates. I wanted a maximum date only at the product level not for the entire table.

Comment: Well, your sample contained one product only. Then you must filter for _ProductID_ by joining on this to the table holding the products.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to have groups, so why use `group by`?

```
SELECT 
*
FROM your_table
WHERE AuditVisit = (SELECT MAX(AuditVisit) FROM your_table)
```

Pretty self-explaining, I think.

Comment: Thanks for quick response but the above code wont work as my table has multiple products and those products have different stores and different max AuditVisit dates and the above query will calculate the max data in the entire column where I need the max date only for the distinct record at the product level

Answer (score 1):

If you want one record in MS Access, then you need to be very careful with `SELECT TOP`.  It is really `SELECT TOP WITH TIES`.

Hence, the obvious answer of:

```
Select Top 1 *
From t
Order By AuditVisit Desc;
```

would return multiple rows if multiple rows have the same date.  If you really want one, then you want to add a unique column as the last key in the order by:

```
Select Top 1 *
From t
Order By AuditVisit Desc, id;
```

I don't see such a key in your data, although you might have a combination of columns that are unique in each row (multiple columns can be added to the `ORDER BY`).

In MS Access -- even more so than in other databases -- primary keys are important on tables for this reason.